# Is there a way to disable cssnano in nuxt 3 projects?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I am using Unocss in a Nuxt 3 project and it seems that Uno has a problem with cssnano. Nuxt framework uses cssnano under the hood. Is there a way to temporarily disable cssnano in Nuxt 3 projects?

I read the documentation of the Nuxt site in [this link](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config#postcss) about configuring it but I did not understand how to configure a postcss plugin in nuxt.config.ts file.

Answer (score 0):

In Nuxt 2 you can disable cssnano by changing the build configuration in your nuxt.config.js file.

1. Open your nuxt.config.js file
2. Inside the build object, add the postcss key if it doesn't already exist, and then set the cssnano option to false:

```js
export default {
  build: {
    postcss: {
      preset: {
        cssnano: false,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Maybe this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Disable cssnano in Nuxt 3:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  postcss: {
    plugins: {
      cssnano: false,
    },
  },
})
```